# Converting canvas to PNG returns blank image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am experiencing an issue with converting a canvas to PNG.
Although the canvas looks exactly as I want it and the conversion from canvas to data URL PNG seems right, the image is blank.
I also tried converting a div to PNG but it did not work for me because I wanted a greyscale filter to be applied. Anyone have any ideas?

---

### JavaScript

```
var imgis = new Image();
var bubble = new Image();
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
bubble.onload = function() {
  var imgis = new Image();
  var bubble = new Image();
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  bubble.onload = function() {
  // set the canvas' size
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  // first fill a rect
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // set the gCO
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'luminosity';
  // if the browser doesn't support Blend Modes
  console.log(ctx.globalCompositeOperation)
  if (ctx.globalCompositeOperation !== 'luminosity')
    fallback(this);
  else {
    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(imgis, 30, 60);
    // reset the gCO
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  }
}
imgis.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
bubble.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
imgis.src = "image1 src";
bubble.src = "image2 src";
function fallback(img) {
  // first remove our black rectangle
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(imgis, 30, 60);

  // get the image data
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var d = imgData.data;
  // loop through all pixels
  // each pixel is decomposed in its 4 rgba values
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
    // get the medium of the 3 first values
    var med = (d[i] + d[i + 1] + d[i + 2]) / 3;
    // set it to each value
    d[i] = d[i + 1] = d[i + 2] = med;
  }
  // redraw the new computed image
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
 }

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas);
 console.log(image.src);
 // document.getElementById('theDemo').src = image.src;
 var image_data = $(image).attr('src');
 console.log(image_data);
 $("#theDemo").attr('src', image_data);
```

### HTML

```
<canvas id='canvas' > </canvas>
    <img src="" id="theDemo" />
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console? Are your image URLs cross-origin?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using canvas2image. You should replace `var image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas);` with `Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas, width, height)`. Hopefully that helps!

**EDIT** Since the issue is with the actual canvas to base64 conversion, you can try to use the `.toDataURL()` method instead of using that library. My comment explains how to test this in your specific code.

Comment: i just tried it, the difference is that now it prints a blank image with the specified width and height.

Comment: Copy the `image.src` it's logging and paste it into a new browser tab. If that is the right image, then you should edit the last line of your code to this: `$("#theDemo").attr('src',image.src);`

Comment: I consoled log the src and opened the url in a new tab  and its the same thing,  blank.

Comment: Then the conversion with `Canvas2Image` is incorrect, or just not in the expected format. You could try this: `var image_data = canvas.toDataURL();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: I did try that approach with type image/png but it didnt work either.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Did you post all of your code? You only used jQuery at the very end, please make sure you have that linked in the HTML also.

Comment: i included all the code but i dont think there something wrong with that.

Comment: There wouldn't be a problem if you have correct code. Have you linked jQuery and Canvas2Image in your html? Have you posted all HTML?